# Is it possible to " Select N times"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Unfortunately, the data model for my database must change so I am looking for the most painless way to migrate my data.

How it is at this moment:

```
create table cargo{
  id serial primary key,
  person_id int,
  weight_id float,
  reps_id int
);
//skipping constraints declaration
```

However it happened that person is able to lift different values of cargo each turn

What I am going to do is modify `cargo` table and add `turn` table like this:

```
create table cargo{
 id serial primary key,
 person_id int,
 );
//skipping constraints declaration

create table turn{
  id serial primary key,
  cargo_id int,
  weight float
);
```

normally I could migrate existing data like this:

```
insert into turn (cargo_id, weight) select id, weight from cargo;
```

but this way I am losing all of `reps` where `reps` > 1

Is it possible to create insert into select, where select would be called as many times as `reps` count without making script?

Comment: Where is reps_Id being stored in the new schema?  you could recursively create a table for the max number of reps, and then join to it when less than the desired count for each cargo...  so... "Is it possible to create insert into select, where select would be called as many times as reps count without making script?" ***I would think so.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
-- insert into turn (cargo_id, weight) 
SELECT c.id, c.weight_id
FROM cargo c,
LATERAL (
  SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, greatest( c.reps_id, 1 ) )
) xx;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4923e/1

Comment: you don't need a derived table. `from cargo c, generate_series(...)` will do just fine

Comment: that works great ! I would have never thought about doing this like that. It seems that I have a lot to learn, Thank You very much !